# hyperopt - is it possible to get the current value of its search space?

Tags: python, xgboost, hyperopt

I am wondering if there is a way to access the current value chosen by hyperopt for parameters? I would like to use its selected value in a learning rate callback function for xgboost.

```
from hyperopt import hp
param = {'eta' : hp.uniform('eta', 0.01, 0.1)} # learning rate
param['eta'] # returns <hyperopt.pyll.base.Apply at 0x23fd5699dd8>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll get the value for 'eta' for each iteration of your objective function
when using **fmin**.

E.g.

```
 _ = fmin(fn=objective,
           space=param,
           max_evals=num_trials)
```

And objective is defined as:

```
def objective(params: Dict):
    # So you can access  params['eta'] in this context
```

Comment: I don't believe the current chosen eta is accessible; just tried it again, yielding error: `len of pyll.Apply either undefined or unknown`

Comment: Sorry I misspelled params['eta']. But you access directly from the dictionary you receive as parameter in your objective function, without pyll. 
Just doing params['eta'].